# List to Printable page

Tags: excel

I am trying to export an excel file, then pull a single column from that list into a multi-column file that is printable for individuals without access to excel.
I can't seem to find a way to reliably get the next page to start where the first page ends, without manually making formula for each page, and my data ranges will require dozens of pages.
Putting in the formula, or using an =offset is just providing me with the correct range when manually inputting, but when attempting to duplicate it, it's not following the same pattern.

I've made several pages as a temporary solution.
Currently I have page 1 with cell A1 =Input!C2, and cell A47 as =Input!C48, Cell D1 as =Input!C143, Cell D47 as =Input!C189, to create a data list.  but when I try to copy it down to page2, it puts A48 as =Input!C49, when I need =Input!C190 and doing two full pages so it will recognize the pattern will just make it jump back and forth between full pages as it advances, not even giving the accurate cells on each page.

I looked into offset and vlookup, but every formula I try provides the same issue of not providing the list in order.  the list is already pre-sorted in ascending, I just need it to be split into multiple columns.